# Workaround for Core_extended.Shell.run on 32-bit machines

Tags: curl, ocaml, ocaml-core

I'm running into trouble (again) with Jane Street's `Core` library. I'm trying to run `curl` from an OCaml piece of code, using the following line:

```
Core_extended.Shell.run_full "curl" [url];;
```

I know for sure that `curl` is installed and working on my machine, but, at runtime, I get the following error, raised on the `curl` line:

```
Uncaught exception:
    (Failure "unsupported on 32bit machines")
```

The message makes it very clear what's happening here, but I've been looking for a workaround and haven't found anything relevant. Any idea?

Comment: got the same issue....  on my code, I have used Sys.command("curl ...") which runs fine...

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to use `Core_extended` to run programs from OCaml. You can start with the portable `Sys.command`, and if doesn't suite you, then you can use a family of OCaml standard functions for process management in the `Unix` module, e.g.,  `Unix.open_process_in` that will create a process with the given arguments and return a channel from which you can read its output (aka `popen`).

What concerning your original problem, then I would suggest you to file an issue on their [bug-tracker](https://github.com/janestreet/core_extended/issues). But before you do this, make sure, that you have the latest version installed.